# Update deployment labels using "kubectl patch" does not work

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to update a label using kubectl.

When I use `apply` it works but it doesn't when doing a `patch`.

I tried `kubectl patch deployment nginx-deployment --patch "$(cat nginx.yaml)"`; it returns back `no change` where I would expect to get back a label change.

These are the only changes on my yaml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: testLab
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: helloWorld
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Is there a restriction on what patch updates or it am I doing something wrong?

I also tried specifying `--type strategic` and other types but none seem to work.

Comment: There is no key `label` under `metadata` for a `Deployment` resource.  See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#deployment-v1-apps) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#objectmeta-v1-meta). There is a **`labels`** key (plural). When I try to apply a resource that matches what you're showing, I get an error `error validating data: ValidationError(ConfigMap.metadata): unknown field "label" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta;`. Can you please update your question?

Comment: My bad i was actually using labels. i just mistyped. Copied and pasted the yaml im using now.

Comment: Can you show `kubectl version --short`?

Comment: Client Version: v1.13.1

Answer (score 1):

After executing command  **kubectl patch** on your second file (where you changed label) you should see following error:

```
Error from server: cannot restore map from string
```

After executing command **kubectl apply** on this file you should get following error :

```
error: error validating "nginx.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.metadata): unknown field "label" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Your deployment file should looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: helloWorld
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8
```

You missed to add space after app label.

Add space and then execute command `kubectl patch deployment nginx-deployment --patch "$(cat nginx.yaml)"` once again.

Here are useful documentations: [labels-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/), [kubernetes-deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), [kubernetes-patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

Comment: FYI: the label still doesnt get updated in this case, thats your reply is exactly what I tried before when asking the question.
I just had a typo when I pasted the yaml in the question above so I've correct that as soon as I saw it. The whole point is patch does not work when updating deployment labels. Therefore this answer does not really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be having something like this in your metadata:

```
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    label: testLabel2
```